# How to load tensorflow saved model into memory and never has to load it again after deploying in google app engine?

Tags: tensorflow, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I am using a tensorflow hub model "Universal Sentence Encoder" and sometimes app engine shutdowns automatically and it takes more time to load this model again. How to make that model stay in memory?

```
   runtime: python
    env: flex
    
    runtime_config:
        python_version: 3
    
    automatic_scaling:
      min_num_instances: 1
      max_num_instances: 1
      cpu_utilization:
        target_utilization: 1
    readiness_check:
      app_start_timeout_sec: 1800
    liveness_check:
      path: "/liveness_check"
      check_interval_sec: 30
    resources:
        cpu: 1
        memory_gb: 6
        disk_size_gb: 15                        
    entrypoint: gunicorn -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker -w 4 app.main:app --timeout 1000
```

Logs:

```
A 2021-03-22T10:53:59Z [2021-03-22 10:53:59 +0000] [8] [INFO] Started server process [8]
 
A 2021-03-22T10:53:59Z [2021-03-22 10:53:59 +0000] [8] [INFO] Waiting for application startup.
 
A 2021-03-22T10:53:59Z [2021-03-22 10:53:59 +0000] [8] [INFO] Application startup complete.
 
A 2021-03-22T11:01:03Z [2021-03-22 11:01:03 +0000] [1] [INFO] Handling signal: term
 
A 2021-03-22T11:01:03Z [2021-03-22 11:01:03 +0000] [8] [INFO] Shutting down
 
A 2021-03-22T11:01:03Z [2021-03-22 11:01:03 +0000] [8] [INFO] Error while closing socket [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
 
A 2021-03-22T11:01:04Z [2021-03-22 11:01:04 +0000] [8] [INFO] Waiting for application shutdown.
 
A 2021-03-22T11:01:04Z [2021-03-22 11:01:04 +0000] [8] [INFO] Application shutdown complete.
 
A 2021-03-22T11:01:04Z [2021-03-22 11:01:04 +0000] [8] [INFO] Finished server process [8]
 
A 2021-03-22T11:01:04Z [2021-03-22 11:01:04 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
```

Comment: There is nothing you can do to keep it in memory after an instance shutdown.

Comment: So each time a user needs an output, it has to load the model?

Comment: @Bilbin, do you understand what an instance shutdown is and when it happens?

Comment: I don't know when it shutdowns? After some inactive time?

Comment: And in logs, it shows gunicorn is shutting down.

Answer (score 0):

With App Engine flex your application is started when deployed (because the min instance is 1, you always have 1 instance started). In your startup routine, add the model loading in memory and keep it in global variable. Like this, any requests that you receive on your service will be able to use it.

However some caveats:

- App Engine flex is restarted at [least once a week](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/how-instances-are-managed) to update the underlying platform. So, once a week, at least, your instance will restart. But because you load your modal at startup, no worries about the request response time!
- When the service scale up (not your case), a new instance is created and thus the model is again loaded in memory
- Similarly, if your instance crash (out of memory for example, or unhandled exception), a new one is created and thus the model is loaded again at this time.